# Quick sort issue c++

Tags: c++

so I'm working on a sorting algorithm and have a selection sort working, but my quick sort seems to have a problem and I don't know how to fix it. Here's my code

```
void SortingCompetition::quicksort(int low, int high)
{

 if (high!=low&& high>low)
{

int one=hash[low];
int two=hash[high];
int three = hash[high/2];
    if((one<=two&&one>three)||(one<=three&&one>two))
    {
        swap(hash[low], hash[high]);
        swap(copyOfWords[low], copyOfWords[high]);
    }
    else if((two<=one&&two>three)||(two<=three&&two>one))
    {

        swap(hash[high/2], hash[high]);
        swap(copyOfWords[high/2], copyOfWords[high]);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    int i=low;
    int j=high-1;
    while(i!=j||i<j)
    {
        while(hash[i]>=hash[high]&&i<j)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while(hash[j]<=hash[high]&&i<j)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if(i==j||i>j)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            swap(hash[i],hash[j]);
            swap(copyOfWords[i],copyOfWords[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(hash[j],hash[high]);
    swap(copyOfWords[j], copyOfWords[high]);
    quicksort(low, j-1);
    quicksort(j+1,high);

}
}
```

I think there's an issue with my swaps, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on debugging, where does the problem lie?

Comment: I'm not really sure. it's giving me highest to lowest instead of lowest to highest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the result to be lowest to highest, change

```
while(hash[i]>=hash[high]&&i<j)
{
    i++;
}
while(hash[j]<=hash[high]&&i<j)
{
    j--;
}
```

to

```
while(hash[i]<=hash[high]&&i<j)
{
    i++;
}
while(hash[j]>=hash[high]&&i<j)
{
    j--;
}
```